# Collecting data from Vector to Map

Tags: java

I wrote the following piece of code and want to hear your opinion, in this snippet I have a vector called `aggregateFeaturesForML` which has elements of Class with 3 fields: sourceip, key, value. what I want is to collect all the key-value pairs that have the same sourceip and form a nice histogram (for each IP the keys are unique), for that purpose I collect the key-value pairs in a map called histogram and then use its toString function to print a `{key=value, key=value}` formation. I store the histograms inside another map called `aggregator`.

Any comments on the readability, writing manner, other stuff will be appritiated.

Definition:

```
private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String> > aggregator;
protected Vector<SingleResult> aggregateFeaturesForML = new Vector<SingleResult>(); //Single result has 3 fields: IP, key, value
```

Code:

```
        String previousIp = aggregateFeaturesForML.get(0).getSourceip();
        if(!aggregator.containsKey(previousIp))
        {
            aggregator.put(previousIp, new HashMap<String, String>());
        }

        HashMap<String, String> histogram = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        for(int iterator=0;iterator<aggregateFeaturesForML.size();iterator++)
        {
            SingleResult sr = aggregateFeaturesForML.get(iterator);
            String ip = sr.getSourceip();

            if(ip != previousIp)
            {
                HashMap<String, String> mapForIP = aggregator.get(previousIp); 
                mapForIP.put(key, histogram.toString());
                aggregator.put(previousIp, mapForIP);

                if(!aggregator.containsKey(ip))
                {
                    aggregator.put(ip, new HashMap<String, String>());
                }

                histogram.clear();
                previousIp = ip;
            }

            histogram.put(sr.getKey(), sr.getValue());
        }
        HashMap<String, String> mapForIP = aggregator.get(previousIp);
        mapForIP.put(key, histogram.toString());
        aggregator.put(previousIp, mapForIP);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Beware of hard-coding the first element of a list like `aggregateFeaturesForML.get(0)`. This can throw an exception is `aggregateFeaturesForML` is empty so you should check for that first.
- Do not compare String with `==` (or `!=`). In the following

  ```
  if(ip != previousIp)
  ```

  you are comparing the Strings `ip` and `previousIp` with `!=`. [Strings are compared](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1743880) using their [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method, so you should have instead:

  ```
  if(!ip.equals(previousIp))
  ```
- Prefer to [program against interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1743880). Instead of

  ```
  HashMap<String, String> mapForIP = aggregator.get(previousIp);
  ```

  use:

  ```
  Map<String, String> mapForIP = aggregator.get(previousIp);
  ```

---

As a side-note, if you are using Java 8, your code could be written a lot more simply using the Stream API, that directly provides a way to group elements with a classifier, using the [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) collector. In this case, when two elements are classified the same way, they are collected into a `Map` with the [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) collector.

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> aggregator =
    aggregateFeaturesForML.stream()
                          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                              SingleResult::getSourceip,
                              Collectors.toMap(SingleResult::getKey, SingleResult::getValue)
                          ));
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer, very important notes! I will take them into account and should try this collector thing!